# Call http request on destroy angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

http request is not executed

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  async ngOnDestroy() {
    await this.microSitioService.cancelarTransaccion(this.tarjetaCreditoService.seguimientoEtapa).then(() => {});
  }
```

I need to execute an http request when the on destroy is executed

Comment: How about invoking a http function in ngOndestroy
httpFunc() {
  this.http.get......
}


ngOnDestroy() {
 httpFunc()
}

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Revised Answer

Ok, this is the format for when you want to make certain onDestroy is called - and also stop navigation away, using $event and preventDefault. I've also added how you can return a message to the browser to describe why nav was halted. You can use this to ensure that the http request is working as intended.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
async ngOnDestroy($event) {
  if (this.componentSub) {
    // handle unsubscriptions
    this.componentSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  await this.microSitioService
    .cancelarTransaccion(this.tarjetaCreditoService.seguimientoEtapa)
    .then(() => {});

  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.returnValue = 'A message.';
}
```

Side Note: Have you included `onDestroy` as an implements on the class definition?

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
class MyComponent implements onDestroy {
```

Comment: this does not work, the http request still does not run

Comment: Updated to show a means of halting the navigation away so you can test http request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an event that executes when the angular app is destroyed, you can use the `PlatformRef` which has an `OnDestroy()` callback

in main.ts

```js
function doSomethingOnAppDestory() {
  console.log('test');
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {

  // Ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.
  if (window['ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;

  ref.onDestroy(doSomethingOnAppDestory);

  // Otherwise, log the boot error
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

See the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2qngc?file=src%2Fmain.ts)